# Skip 404 links with fancybox2

Tags: fancybox-2

I have images located on another server (different domain, so I can't use javascript to check) and I'd like fancybox to skip the image and move on to the next if there was an error loading. Is this possible?

Comment: are you linking to your images with a regular link (`<a>` tag) ?

Comment: Not at the moment but I could. Only limitation I'd like is that the url should come from a json call.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: So my initial answer was just bad, I'm getting rid of it. Forget it ever happened. The concept was decent but I forgot about cross-domain policy, so I combined a few other methods to make this work. This won't require you to write your own back-end code, but I recommend you replace the YUI with your own code that does something similar. 
Tested with jsfiddle.

The underlying thing here is you need to make sure that you can just get this working via making sure the server responds as you'd expect. So I'm using your gravatar and mine as tests, and the YUI framework to perform the actual request (via a json request in jquery).

```
var images = ["https://en.gravatar.com/userimage/3532627/52159e585800d69265e0a1819c4dde54.jpg?size=80","http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e08d91a83ce8dd7b88aaaae4aec58074?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"],
    imagelen = images.length,
    newimages = [];
while(imagelen--) {
  var url = images[imagelen];
  $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
            "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
            encodeURIComponent(url)+
            "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
    function(data){
      console.log(data);
      if(data.results[0]){
        // sweet
        newimages.push(images[imagelen]);
        images.splice(imagelen,1); 
        if (images.length === 0) { // last one, fire callback
          doFancyBoxStuff();
        }
      } else {
        // d'oh!
        images.splice(imagelen,1); 
        if (images.length === 0) { // last one, fire callback
          doFancyBoxStuff();
        }
      }
    }
  );
}
function doFancyBoxStuff() {
  console.warn("fired callback");
}
```

Comment: Looks like I'm running into some cross domain problems with this approach. That other server returns a 200 code but firebug shows an error, the xhr object has a status of 0 and the error callback is always called. Also looks like the while loop finishes quite quickly and imagelen is fully counted down by the time the callbacks execute.

Comment: I realized after I wrote this that it could potentially have that problem of counting down too fast because the asynchronous calls should all technically happen at once. Therefore the last one is fired immediately after the first one and this calls back before it's ready, which is my fault on the understanding here. I'll fix that in the example, but the real problem might just be the xhr across domains: I think a JSONP request is the only true cross-domain method. Let me look into this further and if I get something working I'll update this code.

Comment: I gave up on this and just did it server side. Done in minutes. The web is a pain.

Comment: ha! Yeah javascript locks down xhr to avoid cross-site scripting, and that's honestly probably not a bad idea. I was essentially doing what I'm sure you eventually did, I just used middleware instead, which can be good if you have a crapton of images, this will reduce load on your server. For the purposes of this I would have just done it server-side myself.